# Firebug issue - "this.Z.isActive is not a function."

Tags: javascript, youtube, firebug

The code below is just one line that I'm having trouble with. Everytime I try to load Youtube's Advanced Video Uploader with firebug(Because the upload fails if I don't use a breakpoint) It always stops loading and says "this.Z.isActive is not a function" How do I fix this? I'm a noob at this script stuff, so please go easy with the technical terms, lol.

```
var xh = function (a) {
    var b = "JAVA_UPLOADER_" + zh++,
        c = ee(document.body),
        d = c.C("applet", {
            id: b,
            archive: a.o,
            code: "com.google.uploader.service.client.applet.UploaderApplet",
            width: a.pc,
            height: a.pc,
            style: "position: absolute; top: -" + a.pc + "px; left: -" + a.pc + "px;"
        });
    Ah(a, new za("appletloadstart", a));
    c.appendChild(document.body, d);
    a.Z = d;
    a.ma.info("Inserted applet into DOM with id: " + b);
    Ah(a, new za("appletindom", a));
    a.ge = window.setInterval(y(function () {
        var e = l;
        try {
            if (this.Z && (this.O = this.Z.isActive())) if (this.Bf =
```

Comment: Your code example appears to be incomplete.

Comment: You can't fix Youtube Code or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Additionally, you should [indent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) for readability, which has many benefits. Tim Cooper and lwburk took care of the formatting for you this time, but next time try it yourself. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix Youtube code.

Perhaps you can use [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) on firefox and write your fix. But it will work only for you or whoever you share it.